# How to iterate these record till last record in groovey script used in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have read data from csv file which consist of random ticketnumber from database and I have to iterate these record till last record in groovey script used in Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "iterate"? Normally people go for [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) for reading data from the CSV files as this is the most convenient, fastest and safest way of parameterizing your JMeter test using data from external files.

If you're still looking for a way of reading a file in Groovy it's as simple as calling `new File('you_file.csv').readLines()` function which will return you the [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Here is an example of reading `jmeterw.cmd` file which lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation in Groovy:

```
new File('jmeterw.cmd').readLines().eachWithIndex { line, index ->
    log.info('Line ' + (index + 1) + ': ' + line)
}
```

[image]

More information: [File.readLines()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#readLines())